# Indexing a pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have imported a simple csv into a pandas dataframe in Python:

```
spreadie = pd.read_excel("myspreadie.xlsx")
myvalues = spreadie[['Key','Value']]
```

[image: Data Frame]

The picture above shows what it looks like. So every **Value** has an associated **Key**.  I want to plot a histogram for each set of Values for a given Key. So if Key can take a value from 1 to 50 (say), I will have 50 different histograms. Is there a smart way of doing this? Any help gratefully appreciated. (note, in the picture above SP = Key and SSP = Value)

Comment: Sorry are you just wanting `myvalues[(myvalues['Key'] >= 1) & (myvalues['Key'] <= 50)].hist()`?

Comment: yes, I think so. But when I try that, it actually gives me a histogram over the Key itself (not the values)

Comment: And I only get one histogram for the values. So two in total.

Comment: Sample data would help here (copy and pasteable text much preferred to image), also you might want to focus on just a single histogram before worrying about all 50.  Looking at row 1, I'm wondering if you want to interpret 50.17 as a weight or if you have multiple occurrences of 50.17?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you want something like this:

```
    df['Value'].hist(by=df['Key'])
```

Although I'm not sure that with 50 it will work really good. So maybe toss it into a for loop?

```
   import numpy as np
   for group in df['Key'].unique():
       np.histogram(df[df['Key']==group]['Value'])
```

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. The problem I managed to solve the problem as 

`for k in range (50):
            data_by_key = df[(df['Key'] == k+1)]
            plt.hist(data_by_key[['Value']].values `